# MdiParent Does it change the owner c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that uses MdiParent to create instances of the forms in the container I also have a print button using telerik reporting for this I am using a report busy dialog to show that something is hapening while the report is being generated however the form is not closing once the report is created.

If I launch the forms indvidual this code works fine.

```
Form[] forms = this.OwnedForms;

            foreach (Form f in forms)
            {
                if (f is TrainingReportGeneratingForm)
                    f.Close();
            }
```

but if i launch from the parent form it does not using the code below

```
EmployeeQualSkillForm form = new EmployeeQualSkillForm(employeeId, employeeName);
                    form.MdiParent = this;
                    form.PamsSysdbfBizLogic =  pamsSysdbfBizLogic;
                    form.Show();
```

this generating form is called as such from the print button

```
    TrainingReportGeneratingForm form = new TrainingReportGeneratingForm();
                form.CancelGeneration += OnCancelGeneration;
                form.Show(this);
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Use the MdiChildren property instead.  Or better yet, just don't lose the "form" reference you got, store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck on this I had to do this instead

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
   if (frm is TrainingReportGeneratingForm)
      {
         frm.Hide();
      }

}
```